# Como sortear palavras de um array sem repetir as mesmas?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou fazendo um projeto da faculdade em que  preciso simular a loteca, então tenho um array com o nome de 20 times e preciso sortear 10 times mas sem repetir nenhum e apresentar esses times numa *ListBox*, porém não estou conseguindo, poderiam me dar sugestões de como criar esse método de sorteio?

E se possível, algum jeito de adicionar os valores de um *CheckBox* em um *array* para fazer a comparação com os times sorteados.

Meu *array*:

```
public String[] times =
          {
                "Corinthians"
                ,"Palmeiras"
                ,"Santos"
                ,"Grêmio"
                ,"Cruzeiro"
                ,"Botafogo"
                ,"Flamengo"
                ,"Vasco da Gama"
                ,"Atlético-PR"
                ,"Atlético"
                ,"São Paulo"
                ,"Chapecoense"
                ,"Bahia"
                ,"Fluminense"
                ,"Sport Recife"
                ,"Coritiba"
                ,"Ponte Preta"
                ,"Avaí"
                ,"EC Vitória"
             };
```

Comment: Como mostra a pergunta original, não faça uso de `Random` repetidamente, use ele apenas para embaralhar. A resposta aqui é quadrática e tem performance ruim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro declare um Random

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Faça o random pegar um valor no meio do array pelo random gerado no index

```
int r = rnd.Next(times.Length);
```

Agora você consegue pegar seu time:

```
var timesorteado = ((string)times[r]);
```

Aí gere uma lista e adicione.. e filtre para não adicionar duplicado

Fiz um exemplo simples em uma aplicação console, mas pode ser melhorado.. mas só pra te dar idéia da lógica, não esqueça do `using System.Linq;` e `System.Collections.Generic;`

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String[] times =
    {
        "Corinthians", "Palmeiras", "Santos", "Grêmio", "Cruzeiro", "Botafogo", "Flamengo", "Vasco da Gama",
        "Atlético-PR", "Atlético", "São Paulo", "Chapecoense", "Bahia", "Fluminense", "Sport Recife",
        "Coritiba", "Ponte Preta", "Avaí", "EC Vitória"
    };

    var lstTimesSorteados = new List<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var timesorteado = Sorteio(times);

        if (!lstTimesSorteados.Any(x => x.Contains(timesorteado)))
        {
            lstTimesSorteados.Add(timesorteado);
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
}

private static string Sorteio(string[] times)
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    var r = rnd.Next(times.Length);
    return ((string)times[r]);
}
```

Depois é simples, basta comparar o seu checkbox com o **lstTimesSorteados**.